# Which superhero has been portrayed in movies or TV series by the highest number of different real life actors?

Tags: super-hero

The most likely candidates are Superman and Batman but there may have been a couple of other timeless heros who were portrayed by numerous actors over the years. The definition of 'superhero' in this context can be expanded to include such worthies as Hercules, Tarzan, etc.

Comment: Quick question, When you consider Hercules or Tarzan, I have to ask, are you counting on animated versions that were voiced by different actors?

Comment: Oh, I misread the question, in that case, I apologize folks

Comment: @Chris -To clarify a bit; How many different real life actors over the years have portrayed the character Batman? Have more actors portrayed Superman, Hercules, etc.? What superhero has had the most number of 'real life actors' portray them?

Comment: I modified the question to clarify.

Comment: He’s not really a superhero, but Sherlock Holmes has the world record for most portrayals by different actors for a fictional character: http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/2012/5/sherlock-holmes-awarded-title-for-most-portrayed-literary-human-character-in-film-tv-41743/

Comment: James Bond, naturally.

Comment: How about Jesus of Nazareth?

Comment: Do voice actors count?  Or are you only looking for live action portrayals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also Tarzan -- according to [this page](http://www.squidoo.com/Actors_Who_Have_Played_Tarzan), he has been played by Elmo Lincoln, Gordon Griffith (as a child), James Pierce (Edgar Rice Burroughs' son-in-law!), Gene Pollar, Frank Merrill, Herman Brix, Johnny Weissmuller, Buster Crabbe, Glenn Morris, Denny Miller, Lex Barker, Gordon Scott, Jock Mahoney, Mike Henry, Ron Ely, Miles O'Keeffe, Christopher Lambert, Joe Lara, Wolf Larson, Caspar Van Dien and Travis Fimmel. That's twenty-one, just beating Hercules.

Comment: Nicely done, I missed all those guys :-(. I was staying away from child and voice actors though as well as theater productions and commercials. Less the kid, that puts Tarzan and Hercules at a 20-20 tie.

Answer (score 3):

> The most prolific character seems to be Hercules. At least twenty actors have put on the loincloth to portray the Greek god. Some better than others.

The first and most successful of these was Steve Reeves. Other actors who played Hercules were Gordon Scott, Kirk Morris, Mickey Hargitay, Mark Forest, Alan Steel, Dan Vadis, Brad Harris, Reg Park, Peter Lupus, Michael Lane, Samson Burke, Arnold Schwarzenegger, Lou Ferrigno, Brian Thompson, Richard Sandrak, Dwayne Johnson, Kellan Lutz, Kevin Sorbo and Mark Addy.

Second place goes the Man Of Steel. Thirteen is the number for the Kryptonian;

1939 - Ray Middleton, 1948 - Kirk Alyn, 1951 - George Reeves, 1961 - Johnny Rockwell, 1966 - Bob Holiday, 1978 - Christopher Reeve, 1979 - Tayfun Demir, 1988 - James Hayes Newton, 1989 - Gerard Christopher, 1993 - Dean Cain, 2001 - Tom Welling, 2006 - Brandon Routh, 2013 - Henry Cavill

Seven actors have played Batman:
Lewis G Wilson, Robert Lowrey, Adam West, Michael Keaton, Val Kilmer, George Clooney, Christian Bale

Some of the other notable superheroes apparently have apparently only had a single handful of actors' portrayals.

> Note: These do not include child actors or Broadway/stage productions. Neither does it include voice actors or TV commercials.